# How to remove unnecessary numbers in DateTime

Tags: flutter, dart

So, when I print DateTime.now() value, it shows those unnecessary numbers(on the screen the numbers are 323884). Is there any possibility on removing those numbers?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbGNT.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `DateFormat` class.

First import intl package:

```
import 'dart:intl';
```

The use it like this:

```
print(DateFormat.yMd().format(new DateTime.now()));
```

You can use any format you'd like. See the docs for more formats

Answer (score 0):

Let's Try This

```
import datetime
date=str(datetime.datetime.now())
date.split('.')[0]
```